# Is there a way to do priority join that looks up value based on multiple date range criteria using SQL in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Example:

Rate table

| Country | Code | Start | End | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Belgium | A | 2023-01-01 | 2023-03-03 | 0.5 |
| Japan | B | 2020-01-01 | 2021-01-01 | 0.1 |
| Japan | B | 2020-03-01 | 2020-12-31 | 0.2 |
| Japan | B | 2021-02-01 | 2022-12-31 | 0.3 |

Sales table

| Country | Code | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Japan | B | 2020-04-01 |
| Japan | B | 2023-01-01 |
| Japan | B | 2019-12-01 |
| Japan | B | 2021-01-15 |

Result table

| Country | Code | Date | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Japan | B | 2020-04-01 | 0.2 |
| Japan | B | 2023-01-01 | 0.3 |
| Japan | B | 2019-12-01 | 0.1 |
| Japan | B | 2021-01-15 | 0.1 |

Trying to do a look up on rate to join back into sales table so for example

- Priority 1: If the sales date is between multiple date range, pick the latest start date
- Priority 2: If the sales date is not in any range, pick the completed before start date
- Priority 3: Last case disregard date range, and just maps by country and code

This is what I did but I am wondering if there is a more efficient or cleaner way of doing this?

```
select 
    country, code, date, 
    coalesce(b.rate, b1.rate, b2.rate, b3.rate) rate 
from 
    sales_table a
left join 
    rate_table b on a.country = b.country 
                 and a.code = b.code
                 and a.date between b.start and b.end 
                 and b.start = (select max(r.start) from rate_table r 
                                where a.country = r.country 
                                  and a.code = r.code 
                                  and a.date between r.start and r.end)
left join 
    rate_table b1 on a.country = b1.country 
                  and a.code = b1.code
                  and a.date >= b1.start 
                  and b1.start = (select max(start) from rate_table r1 
                                  where a.country = r1.country 
                                    and a.code = r1.code 
                                    and a.date >= r1.start)
                  and b.start is null
left join 
    rate_table b2 on a.country = b2.country 
                  and a.code = b2.code
                  and a.date <= b2.start 
                  and b2.start = (select min(start) from rate_table r2 
                                  where a.country = r2.country 
                                    and a.code = r2.code 
                                    and a.date <= r2.start)
                  and b.start is null 
                  and b1.start is null
left join 
    rate_table b3 on a.country = b3.country 
                  and a.code = b3.code
                  and b.start is null 
                  and b1.start is null 
                  and b2.start is null;
```

Comment: What results would you expect for Japan, B, 2021-01-15?  0.1 or 0.3?

Comment: @dougp i expect 0.1

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method using sequential queries.  I have included inputs and expected outputs first, then the `q1` and `q2` queries do the work.  The final query presents the expected results and `q2` side-by-side.

My solution demonstrates one possible solution, but is written for SQL Server.  You may need to make some adjustments for Snowflake.

Based on your original inputs, I assume Japan, B, 2021-01-15 should return 0.1 because it is 3 days closer than the date range for 0.3.  I have adjusted inputs to demonstrate and edge case.  My sample inputs include a sales date of 2021-01-16 and in the Rate table I have moved the EndDate for the 0.1 row to 2020-12-31.  That puts the sales date the same distance from three possible matches.  You should define the business rules around edge cases like this.

```
with 
rate (    Country  , Code  , StartDate  , EndDate  , Rate) as (
        select 'Belgium', 'A', {d '2023-01-01'}, {d '2023-03-03'}, 0.5
  union select 'Japan',   'B', {d '2020-01-01'}, {d '2020-12-31'}, 0.1
  union select 'Japan',   'B', {d '2020-03-01'}, {d '2020-12-31'}, 0.2
  union select 'Japan',   'B', {d '2021-02-01'}, {d '2022-12-31'}, 0.3
),
sales (    Country  , Code  , SalesDate) as (
        select 'Japan', 'B', {d '2020-04-01'}
  union select 'Japan', 'B', {d '2023-01-01'}
  union select 'Japan', 'B', {d '2019-12-01'}
  union select 'Japan', 'B', {d '2021-01-16'}
),
expectedResults (    exCountry  , exCode  , exSalesDate  , exRate) as (
        select 'Japan', 'B', {d '2020-04-01'}, 0.2
  union select 'Japan', 'B', {d '2023-01-01'}, 0.3
  union select 'Japan', 'B', {d '2019-12-01'}, 0.1
  union select 'Japan', 'B', {d '2021-01-16'}, 0.1
),
q1 as (
  select s.Country  , s.Code  , s.SalesDate  , r.Rate  , r.StartDate  , r.EndDate
  , abs(datediff(day, s.SalesDate, r.StartDate)) as diffStart
  , abs(datediff(day, s.SalesDate, r.EndDate)) as diffEnd
  , min(abs(datediff(day, s.SalesDate, r.StartDate))) over (partition by s.Country, s.Code, s.SalesDate) as diffStartMin
  , min(abs(datediff(day, s.SalesDate, r.EndDate))) over (partition by s.Country, s.Code, s.SalesDate) as diffEndMin
  from rate r
    inner join sales s on s.Country = r.Country
                      and s.Code = r.Code
),
q2 as (
  select Country  , Code  , SalesDate  , Rate
  --, StartDate  , EndDate
  --, diffStart  , diffEnd  , diffStartMin  , diffEndMin
  --, case
  --      when SalesDate between StartDate and EndDate then 1
  --  end as isBetween
  from q1
  where case
        when SalesDate between StartDate and EndDate then 1
        when diffStart = diffStartMin
         or  diffEnd = diffEndMin
          then 1
      end = 1
    and (case when diffStart < diffEnd then diffStart else diffEnd end = diffStartMin
      or case when diffStart > diffEnd then diffEnd else diffStart end = diffEndMin)
)

select r.*
, '|' as '|'
, q.*
from expectedResults r
  full outer join q2 q on q.Country = r.exCountry
                   and q.Code = r.exCode
                   and q.SalesDate = r.exSalesDate
order by q.Country
, q.Code
, q.SalesDate
--, q.StartDate
```